# Inner join, Update, select repeated entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, Employees, Assignment in sqlplus.

- Employees (`EmpID`, `Empname`, `EmpSalary`)
- Assignment (`EmpID`, `Assignment#`, `WorkedHours`).

Some `EmpID` are repeated in the assignment table indicating employees working on multiple projects.

My questions are:

1. A query that will only show those employees who are involved in MORE THAN ONE      project.
2. If WorkedHours are more than 15, increase salary by 1000 In employees table.

I have broken my head over these questions, Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is extremely basic stuff.  If you have problems, you need to work through SQL tutorials, especially on aggregation.  I, personally, like [SQL Zoo](http://sqlzoo.net/).

Comment: What queries have you come up with?

Answer (score 1):

Employees who are involved in more than one project:

```
select e.EmpID, e.EmpName
from Employees e
join Assignment a on e.EmpID = a.EmpID
group by e.EmpID, e.EmpName
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

If WorkedHours are more than 15, then increase salary by 1000:

```
update Employees
set EmpSalary = EmpSalary + 1000
from (select e.EmpID, e.EmpName, SUM(a.WorkedHours) TotalHours 
      from Employees e
      join Assignment a on e.EmpID = a.EmpID
      group by e.EmpID, e.EmpName) g      
where g.EmpID = Employees.EmpID and g.TotalHours > 15
```

Comment: thank you very much, the first one worked fine but for the second one i am getting error SQL COMMAND NOT PROPERLY ENDED.

Comment: Someone else edited my code and broke it.  Try it now.

Comment: it shows the error at line three 'from employees AS b'  ..... a general question these letter e,b,g are storing the name 'employee' etc? means they are not important?

Comment: Let me revert the changes back to my original answer.  See if that works.  Yes, the letters are aliases for the tables/queries.  You don't strictly need them in this example, but they usually tend to make things clearer.